# How to manually install Linux Header for my BeagleBone Black running Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cross-compiling, beagleboneblack

I'm using BeagleBone Black with pre-built Ubuntu Precise 12.04 LTS image at http://www.armhf.com/boards/beaglebone-black/bbb-sd-install/.

Everything's fine, but I need to install some packages that require **Linux Header**, and I found nothing suitable with my kernel `uname -r` 3.14.4.1-bone-armhf.com with using apt-cache search linux-headers-$(uname-r)

I found the Linux Header http://s3.armhf.com/dist/bone/linux-headers-3.14.4.1-bone-armhf.com.tar.xz, also released by them, but unfortunately, I dont know how to Install Linux Header Manually, or do something useful with it.

Comment: Just point your packages `configure` to use an include directory where ever you extract them..

Comment: I'm so sorry for my bad Linux knowledge, Artless Noise, but I don't get what you meant, can you give me some steps?
Thank you

Comment: Assuming your package is *Gnu* standard, you can use *[CFLAGS=-Ipath/to/linux-headers](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/Preset-Output-Variables.html#index-CFLAGS-85) ./configure*.  Just look at the *autoconf* documentation and research *crosscompiling* and *linux*.